# Is It Correct to Say ‘Need I Not’?

Tags: modal-verbs, questions

*Need* is utilised as a normal and also a modal verb (similar to ‘can’, ‘shall’...).

*e.g.* I don’t need; I need not.

Is it correct to say *need I not* or *needn’t I* for the interrogative form?

Comment: *If the sun is shining, need I not take an umbrella?*, sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: @WS2: Speak for yourself! It sounds about as weird to me as *If it's raining, want I not an umbrella?*

Comment: An umbrella is a needful thing.
We must needs carry an umbrella even when the sun does shine
for grey clouds may lurk upon the horizon, carrying rain our way.

The usage is somewhat antiquated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Need we report the matter?*, *Need we not report the matter?* They sound alright to me. I probably wouldn't use them when speaking to the milkman *need I not pay you weekly?*. But I might when writing to the Inspector of Taxes *need I not declare the balance in my Swiss account?*

Comment: _Need I/we not_ sounds archaic to me -- it feels like something I'd expect in Shakespearean prose. I think most people would say _Don't I/we need_ these days.

Comment: +1 for an interesting (indirect) observation. Never thought about it before, but this semi-modal is markedly more natural in positive questions (“Need I say more?”) than in negative ones.

Comment: @Janus: I think you have figured it out. With, *"need"* the semi-modal is used mainly in negative statements and positive questions, and the regular verb in positive statements and negative questions. (*Dare* seems to be different ... I don't think many people say *"Don't I dare to ..."*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.  Even though usage of the word *needn't* may be considered antiquated, the phrase:

> [ You | They | We ] needn't worry.

is still widely used.  The modal verb *need* is also widely used in signage and legal language, because it uses less words than the regular verb *need*:

> Minors need not apply.

vs.

> Minors do not need to apply.

Using the modal verb *need* in spoken English may solicit some weird looks from people, but it is technically correct.

Rules of thumb for the **modal** verb *need*:

> [subject] need [regular verb]. -- declaration
>
> Need [subject] [regular verb]? -- interrogative

For example:

> He needn't apply.
>
> You need apply.
>
> Need he go?
>
> Need I stay?

Rules of thumb for the **regular** verb *need*:

> [subject] [verb] need(s) [infinitive verb]. -- declaration
>
> [verb] [subject] need(s) [infinitive verb]? -- interrogative

For example:

> He needs to apply.
>
> You don't need to apply.
>
> Might he need to go?
>
> Don't I need to go?